# PHP PDO - migrating to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

Does anyone know if there is a viable library for PDO database access for CodeIgniter?  I only ask because I am in the process of migrating over to CI and am having trouble integrating my old Database classes as libraries in the CI framework - can't seem to get them to utilize CI's config constants for database access.  Any thoughts?  It would help make my implementation a little more database-flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the following URL:

- [CodeIgniter - PDO-SQLite3](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDO-SQLite3)
- https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/45247/#223844

Answer (score 2):

Step by step adding [PDO in Codeigniter Tutorial](http://christopherickes.com/web-app-development/using-pdo-in-codeigniter/).

This thread also discusses [Using PDO in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985672/pdo-in-codeigniter-protect-vs-sql-injection)