# How can I use PDO in CodeIgniter 2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I would like to use PDO instead of the built-in database-classes. But how can I do it? I tried to do the modifications suggested in a [blog post](http://christopherickes.com/web-app-development/using-pdo-in-codeigniter/). I commented out a part of `system\database\DB.php` and also added:

```
$DB = new PDO(
$params['dbdriver'].':host='.$params['hostname'].';dbname='.$params['database'],
$params['username'], $params['password']);

return $DB;
```

But now my PHP-code crashes if I do `$this->load->database();` in a Controller. So how should I use PDO and execute database queries using PDO in CodeIgniter?

I have also tried to use this code in a Controller:

```
foreach($this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I believe there is a config issue in your setup.  The blog post has worked step by step for over 100 developers so far.  Perhaps the database credentials are incorrect?  Otherwise I tried to add some clarification below.  Will help you to solve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");  
$stmt->execute();  
foreach ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
      print_r($row);
}
```

Or:

```
foreach ($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users") as $row) {  
     print_r($row)."\n";
}
```

Learn more about 3 PDO database calls here...

[PDO Query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)
[PDO Exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)
[PDO Prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

EDIT:  Also check your `app/config/database.php` file for the following settings:

```
$active_group = 'default';  
$active_record = FALSE;  

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'YOURHOSTNAME';  
$db['default']['username'] = 'YOURUSERNAME';  
$db['default']['password'] = 'YOURPASSWORD';  
$db['default']['database'] = 'YOURDATABASE';  
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';  
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';  
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;  
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;  
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;  
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';  
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';  
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';  
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';  
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;  
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this error message from CodeIgniter: `Message: Undefined property: Mycontroller::$db` doesn't I have to load the `$db` variable in some way?

Comment: From that blog post, did you follow step 2?  Be sure that `return $DB;` is still active -> NOT COMMENTED OUT.   Also, did you autoload the database library?  Otherwise add `$this->load->database();` to your constructor.

Comment: Yes, I did as you wrote on step 2. But when I run `$this->load->database();` in my controller it doesn't work. I get "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error".

Comment: Is this in your app/config/autoload.php file?  `$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);`  If so, try removing `$this->load->database();` from any models / controllers.  Finally, confirm your database credentials are correct.  Perhaps there is an issue with hostname, server, password and database.

Comment: No, I have it like: `$autoload['libraries'] = array();`

Comment: My database credentials are correct since it works with the default CodeIgniter settings, before I edited `system\database\DB.php` as in the blog post.

Comment: Last thoughts... 1) include `$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);`  2)  check your db settings as outlined above  3) re-copy and paste in the DB.php file as outlined in the blog post.  Have verification from over 100 developers that this has worked so there must be a missing configuration somewhere...

Comment: I had `$active_record = TRUE;` but changed to `FALSE;` now. But it didn't solve the problem. I have also changed to `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');` now, but the PHP script seem to crash when loading the database class.

Comment: What is the error message?  Also, are you using Codeigniter 2.0?

Comment: There was no error message, just HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. But I have solved it now. I upgraded from CodeIgniter 2.0.1 to 2.0.2 and now your trick works. Thanks! You are helpful!

Comment: Great work @ChristopherIckes. This thread has given me the best insight as to integrating PDO with Codeigniter after a bit of research.. and looks to have helped Jonas.

Comment: Does ActiveRecord can't be use with PDO driver?