# What is best way to deal with single quotes & double quotes insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What is best way to deal with `single quotes` **&** `double quotes` insert into `Mysql` database.?
I have tried with many cases.
For example:

I need to store Paesano's Temple

**1.** I have store same but there is problem of sting break

**2.** I have tried with `addslashes` then store in database but there is problem at a time of showing in front-end (it's showing `slashes-need stripslashes` on `fron-end`)

Comment: the best way, definitely, is using prepared statements.

Comment: first post you effort then move on

Comment: What @FranzGleichmann said, because reasons : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use PDO for database operation it will take care regarding this type of query

try this link

[How can I use PDO in CodeIgniter 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884761/how-can-i-use-pdo-in-codeigniter-2)